# Local variable `sp` is reassigned in all paths before being read

Tags: c++, resharper

What is this warning message about, "Local variable `sp` is reassigned in all paths before being read". What could go wrong?

```
SerialPort sp("/dev/netlink6", B115200, loop);

sp.onRead = [&sim](std::string msg) {
    for (auto c: msg) {
        sim.process(c);
    }
};
```

Comment: And you think that's enough code to show?

Comment: Either you have some `sp = ...` somewhere, or at least Resharper thinks that. As manni says: this snippet alone doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: When I remove sp.onRead = ..., the warning goes away.

Comment: Static analysis of C++ is often more a question of heuristics than of facts. (This one possibly because it looks like your constructor didn't fully construct the object, which may or may not be a problem.) AFAIK you can use specially-formatted comments to make ReSharper shut up when you know you're right.

Comment: Could be a ReSharper issue - please show the entire function where this message occurred.

Comment: @IgorAkhmetov That's the entire function.

Answer (score 0):

The message can be a hint that declaration and assignment can be joined:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0; // ReSharper: Local variable 'i' is reassigned in all paths before being read.
    i = 5;
}
```

Can be obviously `int i = 5`.

What causes the message in your case can't be said from the short code snippet. In case the member `onRead` is set in constructor, this shouldn't provoke the message from ReSharper:

```
class A
{
public:
    int i;
    A(const int i) : i(i) {}
};

int main()
{
    A a(0);
    a.i = 5; // No message regarding reassignment.
}
```